# Can I capture ENTER key for an onlick event also with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a button that does a post to my server but I would also like to capture the ENTER key.  Is this possible?

My current click call looks like this:

HTML for my input field:

```
<input class="span3 required" type="text" value="" name="postcode" id='postcode'/>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#update_local').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
});
```

How can I capture an Enter key stroke while in this input field and trigger my click event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do it. `e.which` holds the character code of the pressed key. For enter, we want to check for 13:

```
$('#postcode').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){ //Enter key
        $('#update_local').click()
    }
});
```